# MongoDB MapReduce - How to populate an array in reduce function?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce, nosql

I have a MovieRatings database with columns `userId`, `movieId`, `movie-categoryId`, `reviewId`, `movieRating` and `reviewDate`.

In my mapper I want to extract *userId -> (movieId, movieRating)*

And then in the reducer I want to group all *movieId, movieRating* pair by user.

Here is my attempt:

**Map function**:

```
var map = function() {
    var values={movieId : this.movieId, movieRating : this.movieRating};
    emit(this.userId, values);}
```

**Reduce function**:

```
var reduce = function(key,values) {
    var ratings = [];
    values.forEach(function(V){
        var temp = {movieId : V.movieId, movieRating : V.movieRating};
        Array.prototype.push.apply(ratings, temp);
        });
    return {userId : key, ratings : ratings };
}
```

**Run MapReduce**:

```
db.ratings.mapReduce(map, reduce, { out: "map_reduce_step1" })
```

**Output**: `db.map_reduce_step1.find()`

```
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : { "userId" : 1, "ratings" : [ ] } } 
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : { "userId" : 2, "ratings" : [ ] } } 
{ "_id" : 3, "value" : { "userId" : 3, "ratings" : [ ] } } 
{ "_id" : 4, "value" : { "userId" : 4, "ratings" : [ ] } } 
{ "_id" : 5, "value" : { "userId" : 5, "ratings" : [ ] } } 
{ "_id" : 6, "value" : { "userId" : 6, "ratings" : [ ] } } 
{ "_id" : 7, "value" : { "userId" : 7, "ratings" : [ ] } } 
{ "_id" : 8, "value" : { "userId" : 8, "ratings" : [ ] } } 
{ "_id" : 9, "value" : { "userId" : 9, "ratings" : [ ] } } 
{ "_id" : 10, "value" : { "userId" : 10, "ratings" : [ ] } } 
{ "_id" : 11, "value" : { "userId" : 11, "ratings" : [ ] } } 
{ "_id" : 12, "value" : { "userId" : 12, "ratings" : [ ] } } 
{ "_id" : 13, "value" : { "userId" : 13, "ratings" : [ ] } } 
{ "_id" : 14, "value" : { "userId" : 14, "ratings" : [ ] } } 
{ "_id" : 15, "value" : { "movieId" : 1, "movieRating" : 3 } } 
{ "_id" : 16, "value" : { "userId" : 16, "ratings" : [ ] } }
```

I am not getting the expected output. In fact, this output makes no sense to me!

Here is the python equivalent of what I am trying to do in the reducer (just in case the purpose of reducer wasn't clear above) :

```
def reducer_ratings_by_user(self, user_id, itemRatings):
        #Group (item, rating) pairs by userID
        ratings = []
        for movieID, rating in itemRatings:
            ratings.append((movieID, rating))
        yield user_id, ratings
```

**Edit 1** @chridam

Here is an outline of what I really want to do here :

**Movies.csv** file looks like :

userId,movieId,movie-categoryId,reviewId,movieRating,reviewDate
1,1,1,1,5,7/12/2000
2,1,1,2,5,7/12/2000
3,1,1,3,5,7/12/2000
4,1,1,4,4,7/12/2000
5,1,1,5,4,7/12/2000
6,1,1,6,5,7/15/2000
1,2,1,7,4,7/25/2000
8,1,1,8,4,7/28/2000
9,1,1,9,3,8/3/2000
...
...

I import this into mongoDB :

```
mongoimport --db SomeName --collection ratings --type csv --headerline --file Movies.csv
```

Then I am trying to apply the map-reduce function as define above. After that I will export it back to a csv by doing somethig like :

```
mongoexport --db SomeName --collection map_reduce_step1 --csv --out movie_ratings_out.csv --fields ...
```

This `movie_ratings_out.csv` file should be like :

userId, movieId1, rating1, movieId2, rating2 ,...
1,1,5,2,4
...
...

So each row contains all the (movie,rating) pair for every user.

**Edit 2**

Sample :

```
db.ratings.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f4a0dd9cb74fc4d344a40f"),
    "userId" : 4,
    "movieId" : 1,
    "movie-categoryId" : 1,
    "reviewId" : 4,
    "movieRating" : 4,
    "reviewDate" : "7/12/2000"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f4a0dd9cb74fc4d344a410"),
    "userId" : 5,
    "movieId" : 1,
    "movie-categoryId" : 1,
    "reviewId" : 5,
    "movieRating" : 4,
    "reviewDate" : "7/12/2000"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f4a0dd9cb74fc4d344a411"),
    "userId" : 4,
    "movieId" : 2,
    "movie-categoryId" : 1,
    "reviewId" : 6,
    "movieRating" : 5,
    "reviewDate" : "7/15/2000"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f4a0dd9cb74fc4d344a412"),
    "userId" : 4,
    "movieId" : 3,
    "movie-categoryId" : 1,
    "reviewId" : 2,
    "movieRating" : 5,
    "reviewDate" : "7/12/2000"
}
...
```

Then after MapReduce expected output json is :

```
{
    "_id" : ....,
    "userId" : 4,
    "movieList" : [ {
           "movieId" : 2
           "movieRating" : 5
         },
         {
           "movieId" : 1
           "movieRating" : 4
         }
         ...
        ]
   }
   {
    "_id" : ....,
    "userId" : 5,
    "movieList" : ...
   }
   ...
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include some sample documents and your expected output? I'm pretty sure the aggregation framework can handle this much better and more efficiently.

Comment: @chridam check edit!

Comment: I meant documents from the collection i.e. when you do a query `db.ratings.find()` pick perhaps 5 documents to make the sample and show us your expected JSON output of the aggregation operation from the sample. Otherwise it's a futile effort to try reproduce the problem with the info above. Can you update your question with the sample documents and expected JSON output?

Comment: @chridam check edit 2!

Comment: Hey @chridam! Thanks for the answer. Can you also help me in pointing out how to do this using map reduce functions? Just for practice.

Comment: Sure, when I get the chance I will update my answer with the MapReduce approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to run an aggregation pipeline which consists of a **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stage that summarize documents. This groups input documents by a specified identifier expression and applies the accumulator expression(s). The **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline operator is similar to the SQL's `GROUP BY` clause. In SQL, you can't use `GROUP BY` unless you use any of the aggregation functions. The same way, you have to use an aggregation function in MongoDB as well. You can read more about the aggregation functions here.

The accumulator operator you would need to create the `movieList` array is **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)**.

Another pipeline which follows after the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stage is the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** operator which is used to select or reshape each document in the stream, include, exclude or rename fields, inject computed fields, create sub-document fields, using mathematical expressions, dates, strings and/or logical (comparison, boolean, control) expressions - similar to what you would do with the SQL `SELECT` clause.

The last step is the **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** pipeline which writes the resulting documents of the aggregation pipeline to a collection. It must be the last stage in the pipeline.

So as a result, you can run the following aggregate operation:

```
db.ratings.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$userId",
            "movieList": {
                "$push": {
                    "movieId": "$movieId",
                    "movieRating": "$movieRating",
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, "userId": "$_id", "movieList": 1
        }
    },
    { "$out": "movie_ratings_out" }
])
```

Using the sample 5 documents above, the sample output if you query `db.getCollection('movie_ratings_out').find({})` would yield:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f52636b9c3ea346ab1d399"),
    "movieList" : [ 
        {
            "movieId" : 1.0,
            "movieRating" : 4.0
        }
    ],
    "userId" : 5.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f52636b9c3ea346ab1d39a"),
    "movieList" : [ 
        {
            "movieId" : 1.0,
            "movieRating" : 4.0
        }, 
        {
            "movieId" : 2.0,
            "movieRating" : 5.0
        }, 
        {
            "movieId" : 3.0,
            "movieRating" : 5.0
        }
    ],
    "userId" : 4.0
}
```